# How to create legend in progress bar?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qprogressbar

how to make number follow the bar size?

in this qt designer, i create frame which contain bar, and
qlabel =500\n\n250\n\n0\n\n-250\n\n-500

Is there a way to create legend in this bar?

or can we make qlabel follow the size of bar?'

[Progressbar in normal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PW2z.png)

[Progressbar that get extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTbIw.png)

Comment: Use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). For instance, a horizontal layout with the progress bar on the left, and a vertical layout on the right, then add the labels to that vertical layout.

Comment: @musicamante already try it, but it doesnt work, in my code i just use \n to give space for every number in the qlabel. so when i expand it, its not in the right position of the bar.

or what you mean is i put many label in one vertical layout? not in one qlabel?

Comment: Exactly, use more labels, one for each value.

Answer (score 0):

If I wasn't interested in having accuracy, I would create a structure with layouts like this

```
QHorizontalLayout
-> QProgressBar
-> QVerticalLayout
   -> QLabel (500)
   -> QLabel (250)
   -> QLabel (0)
   -> QLabel (-250)
   -> QLabel (-500)
```

But If accuracy is your priority you should start thinking of making your own custom widget.

p.s. the above is not code, but rather a representation of the widget hierarchy that I suggest. I have just formatted it as a code snippet, just to show the hierarchy  :)